# How to handle two nested siblings, with to_json next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, include, to-json

The to_json ActiveRecord docs say [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) for dealing with two nested models, where comments is nested in posts:

```
  konata.to_json(:include => { :posts => {
                                 :include => { :comments => {
                                               :only => :body } },
                                 :only => :title } })
  # => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
        "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true,
        "posts": [{"comments": [{"body": "1st post!"}, {"body": "Second!"}],
                   "title": "Welcome to the weblog"},
                  {"comments": [{"body": "Don't think too hard"}],
                   "title": "So I was thinking"}]}
```

Suppose I have two models that are nested, **but not deeply nested**. Lets say its a user model and comments model. The nested Models would be what I call nested siblings.

I would like my json to look like this:

```
x = { 
    "Blog": {
        "Comments": [
         {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
         {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "User": [
         {"id":2,"company":"ACME"},
         {"id":4,"company":"BUD"}]
    }
}
```

When I use the include method twice, what I end up is a series of deeply nested json, where users are children of comments. whats wrong?!

```
data.to_json(
        :include => { :blog => {
          :include => [{ :comments => {
            :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
            :methods => [:_type]
          }},
          { :users => {
              :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
              :methods => [:_type]
          }}],
          :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
          :methods => [:_type]
        }},
        :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
        :methods => [:_type]
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `blog` twice?

```
blog.to_json(
    :include => { :blog => {
```

I think, the second `blog` should not be in there. Try this:

```
blog.to_json(
  :include => [
    {
      :comments => {
        :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
        :methods => [:_type]
      }
    }, {
      :users => {
        :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
        :methods => [:_type]
      }
    }
  ],
  :except => SKIPPED_COLUMNS,
  :methods => [:_type]
)
```

Comment: it was simply a typo. Its actually stored in data